# crear modelo en BD usando enfoque CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework

Producto de un prpblema con la base de datos, al momento de realizar un update, se perdieron las definiciones de las tablas.

como aun conservo el modelo en la aplicacion (contexto y entidades), se me ocurrio, usar con ese modelo el enfoque CodeFirst, pero este no se recrea en la base de datos.

he probado usando el contexto leyendo las entidades, o creandolas, pero aun asi, en la base de datos no se refrescan las entidades creadas.

existe alguna alternativa para poder recrear el modelo en la BD, desde .net?

Saludos

Comment: Tu enfoque inicial era DBFirst? Si es así tendrás un archivo `edmx`. Lo abres, pulsando botón derecho del ratón, hay una opción en el menú contextual que se llama `Generate Database from Model`

Comment: si realizas un update quiere decir que usas un modelo edmx, o sea no es Code First, sino sera Database First, ya que sino tendrias que tener el modelo desde codigo

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un modelo `edmx` usa la opcion `Generate Database from Model` de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para generar un script que cree la base de datos en base al modelo